# getstream chat: Using a new JWT token for each server side request

Tags: getstream-io

Following the [GetStream chat API docs](https://getstream.io/chat/docs_rest/#serverside_authentication) I've been wondering if there's any disadvantage in sending a newly signed token with each server-side API request.
That way my server will remain stateless and will allow me to generate very short lived tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Generating a new token for server-side for each request doesn't make much sense because server-side has already full access since using API secret.

If you have multiple API keys, then having the same number of tokens with their respective secrets sounds fair. Here, we assume this is a secure environment because it uses secret to do anything on your account.

If you check server-size SDKs (Go, Python, etc), when you create a client, they actually generate your token and cache it.

However, client side is a different story. JWT is stateless but probably your app needs (session) state management and expiration should be done (logout for example). In this case, 15 mins to expire a token and refresh token under the hood is a pretty common practice.

Short JWT expiration

pros:

- no need for central storage (blacklisting for logout, password change, etc)
- more secure (changed more frequently even if stolen)

cons:

- more processing time/resource are spent to sign a new token (cryptography is slow)
- more network requests for refresh
- bad user experience if token isn't saved, instead kept in memory (needs login and security might be a problem on saving since token could be stolen otherwise)